# Programatically set screen for WinRT app

Tags: winapi, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm looking for possibility to set monitor of WinRT app programmatically.

I'm not limited to WinRT API only, I can use any WinAPI calls too (It's possible to keep WinAPI app or service on target machine).

I've tried to access window handle through process handle but there is no main window for WinRT app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by set screen? Set the screen's what?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no way to programmatically force a Windows Store app to run on a particular monitor (I'm assuming this is what you mean by "screen").

When a Windows Store app is started on a system with multiple monitors, it will always run on the same screen where the Start Screen is displayed. This can (again, AFAIK) only be changed by the user by, for example, using the Win+PgUp/PgDn shortcut.

If you're wondering why, it's a matter of consistency and putting the user in control. They get to decide where their Windows Store apps run, not the developer.

Hope that helps.

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: If you want to pass certification to be in the Windows Store, sure. There should still be an API for LOB and kiosk apps which generally require full control over the environment.

Comment: @Erode - Windows 8 is not intended for use in kiosk environments. Windows Embedded 8, as I mentioned above, is a much better fit for such applications.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that windows store app is regular WinAPI app with own window. So I got it's HWND using `FindWindow(L"Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow", L"APP_NAME")` and used `SetWindowPos` to move it around. It doesn't change "logical" monitor of app , but it can change it's position. It's even possible to stretch it over few monitors.

I know why it is not available without hacks and I doesn't care because it a kiosk mode app, it will never go to the store.

Comment: If the goal is to create a kiosk mode app, you may want to consider using Windows Embedded 8 (http://aka.ms/windowsembedded), which is designed to support these scenarios.

Comment: I've looked at it but our deadline is earlier than this OS will be released. (And we need time to test, now we have ready app but few things like monitor and auto-restart, both solved via WinAPI).
Thanks for help.